# http link to download source code from github private repository

Tags: git, github

I am part of an organisation on github with private repositories.
I am trying to integrate with one of the cloud services api where in one of the API I need to provide the URL of source-code (tar.gz) of one of those private repositories.
This works properly in case of public repositories but I want to get this working for private repos as well.

I am aware that issue is because of the authentication. Is there any way of sending the authentication information in the HTTPS url itself?

Something like

```
https://username:password@github.com/Organisation/RepoName/archive/master.tar.gz
```

I have seen many SO questions that describe how this can be achieved   through CURL requests, CURL is not the option in my case. I want to be able to send the URL as a string to the API so that the service can download using the URL

**EDIT**
Additional information:

The external could service that I talked about in the question is heroku. Im creating an app from heroku from one of my scripts using [heroku api](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build-create)
As mentioned in the link I need to send an HTTPS url in the source_blob field. This is were I am trying to send an url to tarball of the private Repo that I am part of

Comment: `CURL is not the option in my case` why not? Github doesn't support (at least, afaik) basic auth for downloading files - you might need to consider passing a url to a script that _does_ send an appropriate request with headers to github and return the response.

Comment: Curl is not the option because I am calling an service API to which I need to send an HTTPS url in the request body using which that service would internally download files

Comment: What is the name of the cloud service you are referring to? It may offer another means you're not aware of.

Comment: Heroku is the service that I am trying to integrate with. I want to be able to create apps on heroku by providing source-blob

Answer (score 3):

If you need a "simple" URL to craw without it to authenticate, you can just create a proxy, in any language you want, that will authenticate yourself on GitHub (using CURL, for instance), and forward the downloaded file to the client.

To answer

> I am aware that issue is because of the authentication. Is there any way of sending the authentication information in the HTTPS url itself?

No, that's not something that HTTP(s) URLs were ever designed to do.

Comment: So you mean to say I need to split it in 2 steps.
1) Download the file using my script save it some where.2)Forward this link to the external service?